# Create a directory if it doesn't exist in TCL

Tags: directory, expect, tcl

I write expect script that login to remote machine and run there some scripts
But I need also to verify the following

Verify if directory `/var/cti/adm/APP` exists.

If APP not exists under `adm` directory , then need to create this directory and add ownership to this directory  , ( as chown system )

Please advice how to check if directory exist in expect script and if not need to create this directory

example of part of my expect script

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect -f
 set multiPrompt {[#>$]}
 send "ssh  $LOGIN3@$IP\r"
 sleep 0.5
       expect  {
       word:  {send $PASS\r ; exp_continue } 
       expect -re $multiPrompt
       }
```

example how we can do it with bash

```
 [[ ! -d /.../..../... ]] && mkdir -p xxxxx
```

Comment: I'm confused. Just plain `mkdir` creates a directory if it doesn't exist and does nothing otherwise. You can pass `--parents` to ensure the whole chain of nested directories exists too. Why do you need a whole script for that?

Comment: I cant just send mkdir , because I want to create dir only in case dir not exsits !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: That's what I mean. If I run `mkdir ~/test` and I already have a directory called `~/test`, nothing happens. If I don't, it gets created. Did you mean something else?

Answer (score 11):

You can do this in pure Tcl without `exec`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set path dir1/dir2/dir3
file mkdir $path ;# [file mkdir] in Tcl is like mkdir -p
file attributes $path -owner system
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [execute](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm) the [`mkdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) command as a subprocess.

```
exec mkdir -p -- $directory
```

If you need to set the ownership as well but only when the directory is created, invoke a shell explicitly.

```
exec sh -c "if ! [ -d \"\$1\" ]; then mkdir -- \"\$1\" && chown -- bob \"\$1\"; fi" _ $directory
```